# Reg: Counter Variable in Thread

Tags: java

I have a requirement that should assign a counter variable for each thread that gets invoked. But I am not getting the expected results, actually the counter is duplicating in the threads. I created a dummy table and a proc to insert the counter value into the table. Is there anyway that the code can be changed so that the thread gets an incremented value.

In the below code, the variable `counter` is a `static int`

```
public synchronized int testSequence(){
 System.out.println("testSequence::::: "+counter++);
 //Random rn = new Random();
 CallableStatement cstmt;
 {
  try {
   cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call insertjtest(?)}");
   cstmt.setInt(1,counter);
   //cstmt.setInt(1, rn.nextInt());
   cstmt.execute();
   cstmt.close();
   conn.commit();
   return counter;
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   return 0;
  }
 }
}
```

But I find the

Comment: the question is not complete and we can provide better answer if we can see the whole class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want :

- independent couters for each thread, you can use a [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variable or an instance variable for each Thread object
- a counter for all threads, you can use an [AtomicInteger](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) variable

EDIT :
After having seen your code, it is one counter for all threads, so you can use an AtomicInteger for all and it is not necessary to be synchronized because AtomicInteger is a multithreaded object.

Comment: Yeah, tried the same AtomicInteger and it worked. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just add volatile to your counter

Comment: yup but AtomicInteger is overkill in this case and on Java < 1.5, you don't have AtomicInteger either :P

Comment: I think you're wrong.. volatile can only be used if the value to write doesn't depend on the current value! Otherwise this solution could lead to a "Lost-Update-Problem".. (see http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_when.shtml)

Comment: Yes, but the problem won't be arisen since the method is synchronized (except of course if the counter is modified in any other methods, which we don't know since the code is not complete and I doubt since it means there is greater problem with the code). See this on Pattern #5: The cheap read-write lock trick http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06197.html

Comment: Hmm.. but what is the volatile good for if you're already using synchronized? There is no advantage on using volatile within a synchronized block/method...

Comment: @Javaguru the problem is without volatile the value of the field can be cached by JVM

Comment: @nanda: OK, it could be cached.. so what you're trying to say is: If you access the variables content, it might be an old (cached) version, right? So volatile helps if you want to read the variable (which is written in a synchronized block) in a non synchronized-block..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to increment the variable `counter` on each invocation of the thread (or its run-method).
Thus, you could try something like:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable) {
  private int myValue;
  public void run() {
    // Call your "routine" ..
    myValue = XXX.testSequence();
    super.run();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to make your counter value either volatile, or an AtomicInt - it's not guaranteed in Java that multiple threads will immediately see updates to variables.